# Can't add Heroku scheduler add-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake-task, paas

In my Rails app, I have a rake task that I want to run periodically. When I try to add the Heroku scheduler add-on to my app, I get this error:

"Could not create resource with vendor, please try again later"

This happens both through the web interface and the console. The command I'm running in the console is:

```
heroku addons:add scheduler:standard
```

The add-on is completely free, but my account is verified with my payment info nonetheless. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Sound like a bug on Heroku, see if it's gone by retrying, else I suggest you send them a support request.

Comment: Heroku was having some issues - https://status.heroku.com/incidents/479